# Using JSON.net to deserialize an object

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm having trouble deserialising a JSON string into an object using JSON.net.

I'm calling the serialisation with:

```
Payload payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(string);
```

However, the resulting `Payload` object is `null`. Any ideas why?

My class:

```
public class Payload
{
    public Payload()
    { }

    public string Action { get; set; }
    public Payload.Bill[] Bills { get; set; }
    public string ResourceType { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }

    public class Bill
    {
        public Bill()
        { }

        public string Amount { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string MerchantId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? PaidAt { get; set; }
        public string SourceId { get; set; }
        public string SourceType { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Uri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My JSON string:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "bills": [
      {
        "id": "xxxx",
        "status": "withdrawn",
        "uri": "xxxx",
        "amount": "5.19",
        "amount_minus_fees": "5.14",
        "source_type": "subscription",
        "source_id": "xxx",
        "payout_id": "xxx"
      }
    ],
    "resource_type": "bill",
    "action": "withdrawn",
    "signature": "xxx"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting payload object is null because the json string structure does not match with your `Payload` class. You need additional wrapper class to deserialize it successfully:

```
public class PayloadWrapper
{
    public PayloadWrapper()
    {
        Payload = new Payload();
    }

    public Payload Payload { get; set; }
}
```

and the deserialization logic:

```
PayloadWrapper wrap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayloadWrapper>(jsonStr);
```

To avoid creating another wrapper class, you can use LINQ to JSON:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
Payload payload = obj["payload"].ToObject<Payload>();
```

where `jsonStr` variable is the json string you posted. Also I noticed that some of the properties in the json string do not match with the property names of the `Payload` class, like `resource_type` in the json string and `ResourceType` in the class. Add `JsonProperty` attribute to them for successful deserialization.

Answer (score -1):

try below one 
The type parameter for DeserializeObject has to be `List<Payload>` instead of string. it would be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Payload>>(json)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Payload>>(json).

Comment: This won't work. The json string is not an array, but it has an array property (bills).

Comment: That doesn't work. I managed to get it working by removing "{"payload": " from the string and the corresponding closing bracket